# Datatables input value not visible on Chromium (Chrome / Opera) browser return

Tags: html, input, datatables, chromium

I have a weird situation happening at the moment, been using [datatables library](https://datatables.net/) for a while and suddenly i discovered that if i have an input with certain value, if i move to another link and then return using the browser back button, the first input value gets empty.

Altough if i inspect the element i can see the value right there in the source code, but not on the screen, if i go back and forward one more time, the second input goes clear, and so on...

I have tested this behavior on multiple browsers and so far, only those based on [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org) (Google Chrome and Opera) seems to be doing this.

Here is an example of my markup

```
<table class="dataTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
     <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="My Text" id="myinput" name="myinput" /></td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I found this option while searching the dataTables documentation:

```
"bStateSave": true,
```

But it seems to do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after posting the question here i noticed something and it solved the problem, not sure why but it's maybe related to the plugin itself.

I didn't had a `name` attribute within the input tag, and that was the cause, after adding a dynamic name the issue is solved.

Hope it helps someone else who can experience this dumb error. :)